# PID control with anti-windup time specifications

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, integrator, specifications

I have scoured the internet for a quite some time now and could not seem to find the answer to this.

Is there a formula that approximates, with these specific gains (Kp, Ki, Kd, Kt), the rise time, overshoot, and settling time for a step response to second order system?

For context, if it is only a PID control with no anti-windup, such formula for second order system can be calculated:

[image: Time domain specification formula]

Where the system is in this form:

[image: 2nd order general equation]

Comment: What is \$\theta\$ in the rise time formula?

Comment: Have you tried looking in Matlab documentation? Maybe you can simulate your system in order to get an answer.

Comment: I [have](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/anti-windup-control-using-a-pid-controller.html). Unfortunately, the documentation only show the advantage of anti-windup and how to implement them. It does not show what should Kt be. Note that Kt is Kb in the MATLAB documentation and it references Astrom's book, which also does not show its time specification :(

Comment: I tried simulating my system using Simulink. Beside trial and error, I don't really know how to systematically get the gains I need. Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: @Chu, its the angle in the s-plane

Comment: I thought that rise time of a second order system was just pi/(2*Wd) where Wd is the damped frequency. What's "the angle in the s-plane" got to do with it? Whatever "The angle in the S-plane" is! The rise time is usually taken to be 1/4 of one oscillation. The cosine of the angle between the line from the origin to a pole and the real axis is zeta, the damping factor. The rise time depends on Wd which depends on Wn and zeta. Also what is kt? I was under the impression that an anti-windup measure would just involve some sort of clamping of the integrator to prevent its output rising too far.

Comment: @James Few things here. Rise time of pi/(2*Wd) or (1.8/Wn) is just an approximation valid for underdamped system ( typically ζ < 0.2). "Angle on S-plane" is the angle between the line from 0 to pole location and the real axis. Kt is a gain used in anti-windup system where the integrator is 'reset' by back calculating. Clamping is another form of anti-windup. Although more crude and simple, clamping often deliver worse performance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that that more complicated form of anti-windup measure based on kt complicates matters in terms of tuning the PID controller and obtaining the values for kp, ki and kd. I don't think that you will find any "formula that approximates" the gains to the required time domain system performance parameters even if Kt was not included.

Tuning a controller and finding suitable values for Ki, kp and kd can be a difficult matter. It can be done using empirical methods such as Ziegler-Nichols or alternatively using an analytical technique.

Without that anti-windup measure (no kt), a way of analytically finding the three gains required to tune the controller to a particular system performance would be to use an I-PD controller (as opposed to a PID controller), determine the I-PD controller's transfer function and then determine the values of Kp, ki and kd by comparing its coefficients to the coefficients of a transfer function which you develop separately by placing poles in particular positions on the s-plane for the required values of zeta and Wn.

The advantage of using the I-PD configuration is that it's transfer function shouldn't contain any zeros which simplifies matters.

Of course to develop a transfer function for a system based around an I-PD controller you need to know the transfer function of the plant which is being controlled.